# Facebook Android Hashkey

Tags: android, facebook

I create my haskhey

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

password: android

and when I want to give it on Facebook on my Developer Settings the option "Sample App" didn't appear.

```
https://developers.facebook.com/settings/developer/profile/
```

Any idea, if I really need this or it's a bug? I am stuck on testing for this one, can I test it another way? I try to create my own keystone and export the apk. Install it on the Phone and didn't work I put the keyhash for the new keystore on the app settings

Edit: Add Code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println("Super init");
        act = this;

        if (isLoggedIn()) {
            System.out.println("Loged IN");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Not Login");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isLoggedIn2() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession(); 

        if(session==null){                      
            // try to restore from cache
            System.out.println("Session null");
            session = Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(act);
        }

        System.out.println("New session");
        if(session!=null && session.isOpened()){ 
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void FacebookLogin() {
        Session.openActiveSession(act, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            // callback when session changes state
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                System.out.println("testing "+isLoggedIn2());
                if (session.isOpened()) {
                    System.out.println("opened");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("NO opened");
                }
            }
          });
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to run a sample app (that's shipped with the SDK), or your own app? The missing "Sample App" is a known bug, and we're working to address that. If you're trying to run your own app, then you should add the key hash to the app's settings page.

Comment: HI @MingLi, thanks for the answer, but yes I try, and I can post to my wall, but I can't initiate any session on any of the sample apps that Facebook gave. And if I can't add a Sample App, how could I test it?

Comment: Yes, this is a known issue. You can follow along the bug report here: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/580981365328061/

Comment: Hi @MingLi thanks, but now How Can I test it? because I suppose to release this app last friday :S

Comment: I guess I don't quite understand what you're trying to do. Are you trying to run a sample that ships with the SDK (like Scrumptious)? Currently, you can't because of this bug, but I don't see how that affects the release schedule of your app.

Comment: Hi @MingLi, Because I can't test the login with Facebook, None of the sample app of Facebook sdk let me login it's weird, but I this it's because the hashkey, I double check on my app settings, and I import the app and distribute it via email, and didin't work. I need to upload to beta play store?

Comment: No, for your own app, you do not need to upload to the beta play store to test. If you're distributing an apk, you're likely using a different keystore than during development, and you need to add that key hash to the app settings too. Please post some of the errors you're seeing (from logcat or your own logging).

Comment: @MingLi, Thanks I see, and my main problem, it's that the session never open I edit my main question to add my code. In that code, on LogCat I always see Not Login or not opened Thanks!

Comment: Is your Session.StatusCallback being called? If not, are you overriding the onActivityResult() method in your activity? And if so, can you print out the "exception" in the call() method?

Comment: Hi @MingLi, Yes call is being called, but let me print exception and I post it here Thanks!

Comment: Hi @MingLi, It works, thanks ! could you put it as answer? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're distributing an apk, you're likely using a different keystore than during development, and you need to add that key hash to the app settings too.